# Purpose of visit: business or tourism?

Tags: change-purpose-of-travel

I'm going to Ljubljana from Vilnius, through Istanbul, for an Erasmus internship. What to write for the purpose of visit: tourism or business?

Comment: It is self evidently not tourism, but could be study rather than business. Perhaps the Erasmus coordinator at your institution can advise you?

Comment: Where do you want to write it?

Comment: When forced to choose between business and tourism, education most certainly counts as business.

Comment: Are you applying for a visa? Visa for where? What is your nationality? What is the nature of the internship - studying or working?